# How can get an instance of a function interface with fields in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

It's not a problem to instantiate a pure function interface or an object interface in TypeScript:

```
interface Fn {
    (something: any): string;
}
var map: Fn = function (something) {
    return '';
}

interface Data {
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}

var data: Data = {
    bar: 1,
    baz: true
};
```

But if I want a function with some fields it's not clear I can get an instance of that.

```
interface FnAndData {
    (something: any): string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}
```

So what do I do to get an instance of such interface?

Answer (score 2):

```
interface FnAndData {
    (something: any): string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}

// Option 1
function fn(x: any): string {
    return 'hello world';
}
module fn {
    export var bar = 4;
    export var baz = true;  
}

var p: FnAndData;
p = fn; // OK

// Option 2
var q: FnAndData = <FnAndData>function x(n: any) {
    var me = <FnAndData>x;
    me.bar = 4;
    me.baz = true;

    return '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the 'elegance' of both :)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface FnAndData {
    (something: any): string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
}

function fn(x: any): string {
    return 'hello world';
}

let p:FnAndData = <FnAndData> fn;

p.bar = 4;
p.baz = true;
```